# Bigcommerce Stencil - Categories Sort Alphabetically

Tags: sorting, categories, bigcommerce

How can I sort the list of product categories alphabetically in the sidebar? I am using Stencil-based template and I found that the template file for this is side-all-categories.html.

I can only find product sorting in the settings, but what the client wants is to sort the categories list not the products under it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the {{sort}} or {{sortBy}} helpers in order to accomplish this. You'd need to wrap them around the category/navigation element.

sort example:

```
{{sort "['b', 'a', 'c']"}}
//=> 'a,b,c'
```

sortBy example:

```
{{sortBy '[{a: "zzz"}, {a: "aaa"}]' "a"}}
//=> '[{"a":"aaa"},{"a":"zzz"}]'
```

Docs for this with stencil are available [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#section--sort-).